# hiding and showing html elements using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I've an html image element like the following and that should be hidden by default

```
<img 
  id="leftL" 
  src="anchors/Left.png"  
  style="
    width: 30px; 
    height: 24px;
    position:absolute;
    cursor:w-resize;
    visibility:hidden
  "
/>
```

But in some situations I need to show the image.

I've tried jQuery `$("#leftL").css('visibility','visible')` and `$("#leftL").show()`.

Both are not working in my case. It will work, however, if I remove `visibility:hidden` from the style and hide it using `$("#leftL").css('visibility','hidden')`.

I am loading big images in my page,so when I use `$("#leftL").css('visibility','hidden')` the `Left.png` will be visible for some time.

Is there any way to overcome this ?

Comment: Can you post the javascript you are using?

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/tmjVP/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of CSS `visibility` property, use `display` property.

This is what jQuery `.show()` & `.hide()` changes, so your visibility states will be consistent.

> This is roughly equivalent to calling .css('display', 'block'), except
>   that the display property is restored to whatever it was initially

http://api.jquery.com/show/

---

Therefore instead of:

- `visibility:visible` use `display:block`
- `visibility:hidden` use `display:none`

Comment: This doesn't answer why `$("#leftL").css('visibility','visible')` isn't working though.

Comment: I tried this.But not working for me.Actually I am using this inside a custom asp.net server control.It was working when I used javascript but after migrating to jquery it is not working

Answer (score 1):

Your code must be like

```
<img 
  id="leftL" 
  src="anchors/Left.png"  
  style="
  width: 30px; 
  height: 24px;
  position:absolute;
  cursor:w-resize;
  display:none;
  "
/>
```

and in jQuery do like `$("#leftL").show();` or `$("#leftL").hide();`

Answer (score 0):

jQuery `show()` and `hide()` methods work on the display style property, not visibility. So you may want to use `display:none` instead of `visibility:hidden` on the image and then you can use the jQuery show and hide methods.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at http://api.jquery.com/hide/ it seems .hide() edits the css property "display"

> If using !important in your styles, such as display: none !important,
>   it is necessary to override the style using .css('display', 'block
>   !important') should you wish for .show() to function correctly.

Does using

```
<div style="display:none"></div>
```

Solve the problem?

Comment: No it is not working for me. Actually I am using this inside a custom asp.net server control.It was working when I used javascript but after migrating to jquery it is not working